Exercise 3.2.11 of Garling (A Course in Mathematical Analysis, Volume 1)
I'm currently working on part (a) of exercise 3.2.11 in Garling's book, and I'm posting a question because I'm having trouble.
Problem $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $t\in\mathbb{R}$, if $nt > -1$, then $(1-t)^{n} \geqq 1-nt$
Hint The book says to use the Average mean-Geometric mean inequality.
Question I approached the problem by splitting the case for $t$, like $t=0, t=1, 0 < t  < 1, -1/n < t < 0$. However, I'm not sure how to use the AM-GM inequality. Even the smallest hint would be helpful, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

It seems I did not read your post carefully enough. Are you sure $nt>-1$ is the correct assumption? $n=3$ and $t=4$ would provide a counterexample. For my proof below I assumed $nt<1$.

I have some doubts about the assumptions given in the problem, but the assumption given in the book is $nt>-1$

Note that
$$
1-t=\frac{(n-1)\cdot 1+(1-nt)}{n},
$$
i.e. $1-t$ is the arithmetic mean of $1$ ($n-1$ times) and $1-nt$. The geometric mean is
$$
\sqrt[n]{1^{n-1}\cdot (1-nt)}=(1-nt)^{1/n}.
$$
Now you can apply the AM-GM inequality.

This is similar to the elementary proofs that $(1+1/n)^n$ is increasing and $(1+1/n)^{n+1}$ is decreasing and approach a common limit in N.S Mendelsohn, An application of a famous inequality, Amer. Math. Monthly 58 (1951), 563.

Based on the counterexample you gave above, it sounds like the assumption in question should probably be modified as you said. Thanks for the help, it was very helpful. Thanks a lot.

This has a standard proof by induction.
I don't see how AM-GM comes into it.
True for $n=1$.
If true for $n$ and
$(n+1)t > -1$ then
$\begin{array}\\
(1-t)^{n+1}
&=(1-t)(1-t)^{n}\\
&\ge (1-t)(1-nt)\\
&=1-nt-t+nt^2\\
&=1-(n+1)t+nt^2\\
&\ge1-(n+1)t\\
\end{array}
$

That was a good solution, thank you.
